# Fetching organization hierarchy from Active Directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to get the hierarchy from Active Directory to display in ASP.NET Web App.I was able to get the manager name out of the user with this.

```
 DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + "jhonDoe" + ")";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
```

With this I'm able to get the manager details in this form.

```
CN=Manager Name,OU=Managers,OU=IT,OU=Central,OU=Springworks,DC=ST,DC=SI,DC=Pri
```

The challenge in this is that if there is another person with the same name how could we identify that it is the manager of that employee?

p.s. Microsoft Delve in Office 365 have organizational hierarchy there and im trying to get the exact same thing in Asp.net

[image: Something like this.]

Comment: Hi! Were you able to get this working? I'm in a similar situation now.